# Calculating sumproduct in list with multiple dataframes

Tags: r, list

I'm doing some simulations and I'm trying to calculate an 'easy' variable that depends on the sumproduct of variables in multiple dataframes. Here is what I'm doing:

```
#Create a dataframe with the formula variables 
month <- 1:120 
price_a <- 5000 #starting point for price_a
price_b <- 6000 #starting point for price_b
demand <- 10 #starting point for demand
data <- data.frame(month, price_a, price_b, demand)

#Create 100 simulations to project price_a and demand for the future
simulations <- 100
intervalo <- seq_len(120)
set.seed(96)
lista_meses <- lapply(setNames(intervalo, paste0("data", intervalo)), function(i) {
  cbind(
    data[rep(i, simulations),],
    growth_pricea = as.numeric(runif(simulations, min = -0.02, max = 0.05)),
    growth_demand = as.numeric(runif(simulations, min = -0.03, max = 0.03)),
    growth_priceb = as.numeric(runif(simulations, min = -0.02, max = 0.02)),
    revenue = demand*price_a
  )
})

#Calculate the growth of each variable 
for (i in 2:length(lista_meses)){
  lista_meses[[i]][["price_a"]] <- lista_meses[[i-1]][["price_a"]]*(1+lista_meses[[i]][["growth_pricea"]])
  lista_meses[[i]][["demand"]] <- lista_meses[[i-1]][["demand"]]*(1+lista_meses[[i]][["growth_demand"]])
  lista_meses[[i]][["price_b"]] <- lista_meses[[i-1]][["price_b"]]*(1+lista_meses[[i]][["growth_priceb"]])
}


#TRYNG TO CALCULATE Z = 1 - sum(price_a*demand)/sum(price_b*demand)
lista_meses[[120]][["z"]] <- 1 -   sum(lista_meses[[1:120]]$price_a*lista_meses[[1:120]]$demand)/ sum(lista_meses[[1:120]]$price_b*lista_meses[[1:120]]$demand)
```

In other words, I want to create in the last dataframe a variable called Z that contains, in each row, the following fórmula:
[image]

As you can see, I'm having trouble with this last step as I don't know how to tell R to do that sum. Does anybody knows how can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df=lista_meses[[120]]
df=mutate(df, Z=(demand*price_a)/(demand*price_b))
df=mutate(df, Z=1-sum(Z))
lista_meses[[120]]=df
```

will create a column named Z with the value `-491.4466` in each entry. (However, note that the summation is from i=1 to 100, not from i=1 to 120, because there are only 100 rows in the last data frame.)